# Find newlines in java nio ByteBuffer

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I am trying to work with a .dat file which contains lines of data. Each line starts with characters sequence e.g. ABC1...99; but will contain a mix of int, long and char. Each line ends with a newline.

I'm trying to detect the new line characters at the end of the row of data, what should I be doing to find the correct newline character.

The code below opens the file, buffers it and prints the buffer as char for debugging purposes

```
RandomAccessFile file2 = null;
try {
    file2 = new RandomAccessFile(sampleFile.dat, "r");
    FileChannel fileChannel = file2.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);
    int bytes = fileChannel.read(buffer);
    bytes = fileChannel.read(buffer);
    while (bytes != -1) {
        buffer.flip();

        while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
            System.out.print((char) buffer.get());
        }

        buffer.clear();
        bytes = fileChannel.read(buffer);

    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        file2.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: use `readLine()` of `bufferReader`

Comment: @BhargavModi I believe converting to String then to byte array will change the data if the character encoding is incorrect

Comment: Use a byte array "\nABC"or "\n" + End-of-File. As ' \n' might falsely be recognized as line end in an int or long (as 10, or 10*256,  ...).